# One of my Intents doesn't work [code on both Activities is the same]

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, callback

[Beginner]
I added an Edit Text on 2 Activities and Intents to share information between them. From 1 to 2 I send question (pop-ups on TextView), from 2 to 1 I send the answer (pop-ups on TextView).

The second part works perfect, but I can't for some reason send the question. What the hеck

MainActivity1 :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var bq: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var runner: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        bq = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bq.root)

        runner = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
        {result: ActivityResult ->

            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val text = result.data?.getStringExtra("Go1")
                bq.t2.text = text
            }


        }
    }
    fun onClickGo2 (view: View) {
        val i = Intent(this, MainActivity2 :: class.java)
        i.putExtra("Go2", bq.ed1.text.toString())
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i)
        runner.launch(i)
    }
}`

MainActivity2 :

`class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var bq: ActivityMain2Binding
    private lateinit var runner2: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bq = ActivityMain2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bq.root)

        runner2 = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
        {result: ActivityResult ->

            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("MyLog", "Результат ${result.resultCode}")
                val text = result.data?.getStringExtra("Go2").toString()
                bq.t4.text = text

            }

        }
    }
    fun onClickGo1 (view: View) {
        val i = Intent()
        i.putExtra("Go1", bq.ed2.text.toString())
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i)
        finish()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will give my reasoning, and at the end the solution.

When we use a contract (`registerForActivityResult`, etc.), we mean that we want to get a result from the `Activity` for which we are "`launching`". That is why the information from the second `Activity` to the first one has successfully passed and applied to the `TextView`.

You have a problem with the fact that the data from the first `Activity` was not transferred to the second `Activity`. In fact, they were transferred with `Intent`, but since the Contract operates unilaterally (as far as I understand), it simply cannot process this data.

The solution to your problem is to use the usual data reception from the `Intent` in the second `Activity`, i.e. the simplest is this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
...

    runner2 = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
    {...}
    
bq.t4.text = intent.getStringExtra("Go2") // That's what you need
}
```

That's all.

You can also experiment with the contract. For example, your example code above (original). Just replace your `fun OnClickGo1` code with:

```
fun onClickGo1 (view: View) {
    val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    i.putExtra("Go1", bq.ed2.text.toString())
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i)
    runner2.launch(i)
}
```

See, the first time you click on the transition to `MainActivity2` (`fun onClickGo2`), you also ask it for data back if it has any.

Next, you click on the element again with `onClickGo1`, so that, according to the new code from `MainActivity2`, go to a `new MainActivity instance` and immediately conclude a contract so that it (`MainActivity new instance`) gives some data back to the `old MainActivity2 instance`.

Next, click again on the `onClickGo2` element to navigate to the new instance of `MainActivity2`.

And here is the most interesting. You have created 4 contracts so far, three of which will work as you wish. Press the `back button` on the phone, and you will see that the `textView` of all previous `Activities` is filled successfully.

Looks like this (*MA - `MainActivity`):

MA1(no data) -> MA2 (no data) -> MA1_1 (no data) -> MA2_1 (no data)

Next press back button on phone: MA2_1 (no data) (click back) -> MA1_1 (filled) (click back) -> MA2 (filled) (click back) -> MA1 (filled) (click back)

Good luck.

Comment: Wish you the best G

Answer (score 0):

In first `Activity`, you put the question in the `Intent` as an "extra" and this is sent to the second `Activity`. However, in the second `Activity` you don't do anything with the "extra" in the launch `Intent`. I don't see any code that takes the "extra" from the `Intent` and put it in the `TextView`.

Comment: ?
wdym, I did wrote the next: 

{result: ActivityResult ->
 if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

val text = result.data?.getStringExtra("Go2").toString() 
bq.t4.text = text }

Comment: You don't understand how `ActivityResult` works. Looks like someone else explained it to you though.